# How can I detect if an app is installed on an android device from within a web page

Tags: javascript, android, detect

Here is the situation:

I have a web page that needs to check through JavaScript if my app is already installed on the android device it is currently running on.

If the app is installed the page will show a link (with custom protocol) to launch the app,
otherwise the page should show a link to the android market.

I can manage the links to app and to market. The only remaining step is to detect the presence of the app on the device from within JavaScript code (or perhaps try to catch a possible error of unsupported protocol as an indication of not existing app).

When I

1. click on a web link with
2. my custom app protocol and
3. the app is not yet installed on the device

I can see that the android environment generates an "protocol is not supported" type error.
Unfortunately, I am not able to capture that error in the JavaScript code to divert the user to the android market.

I guess both direct detection and error detection are valid methods if they exist at all.

Any ideas how can I accomplish that?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use a custom protocol.

Instead, set up your `<intent-filter>` to watch for a well-known URL (e.g., set the scheme, host, and path). That URL should point to the page where your "download the app" instructions lie.

Then, if the user clicks the link to the well-known URL from someplace else, it will launch your app if installed, or will bring up your Web page if not.

Comment: I think this doesn't fully solve the problem. The question is in **how** to check if app is installed on mobile device from javascript. It could be required in cases when webpage need to show either 'download' or 'open' text on the button.

Comment: @YTerle: What you want is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same question, but I solve it like this:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1;
if(isAndroid) { // if is android
    // your app address for local
    var ifrSrc = 'intent://example.com#Intent;scheme=my_scheme;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;end';
    var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
    ifr.src = ifrSrc ;
    ifr.onload = function() { // if app is not installed, then will go this function
        window.location = 'http://your.app_download_page.com';
    };
    ifr.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(ifr);

    setTimeout(function(){
        document.body.removeChild(ifr); // remove the iframe element
    }, 1000);
} else { // if is not android
    window.location = 'http://google.com';
}
```

Hope this can help someone may has this problem.

Comment: Good solution , work fine with me
I only update the ifrSrc to "myscheme=myhosts"

It failed on the samsung old native browser

Answer (score 0):

You can use an iframe which src url is the custom protocol of your app while at the same time you can display your webpage if the custom protocol is not handled. You can also set the iframe to invisble using frameborder="0" and width and height = 0;

Comment: How to check if the custom protocol is not handled (there is no app installed)

Comment: You can't, but you load the custom protocol and load the market after few seconds. If the protocol is handled the page is covered by the app and closed, if not, nothing happens in two seconds and then the page redirects to market.